# update state with onchange event have a delay character

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When i used onchange event to update my state i have a delay character

this is my class

```
var DivInput = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            content: ''
        }
    },
    onChange: function(e) {
        var value = e.target.value
        var name = e.target.name
        this.setState({
            content: value
        });
        console.log(this.state.content)
        this.props.onUpdateState(name, value)
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">{this.props.content}</label>  
                <div className="col-md-4">
                <input onChange={this.onChange} name={this.props.name} type={this.props.type} value={this.state.content} className="form-control input-md" />
            </div>
        </div>
        )
    }
})
```

i have yet initiated my state at '' with getInitialState, and update it when my input change but i have this problem :

if i write : "a"

```
this.state.content = ""
```

if i write : "ab"

```
this.state.content = "a"
```

for input at = "abc"

```
this.state.content = "ab"
```

etc...

Someone has already fixed this problem ?

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState()` does not immediately mutate `this.state` but creates a pending state transition. Accessing `this.state` after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.

See more about it https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html

Comment: thanks but doc doesn't say how i can fix this problem. How can I force state to update

Comment: You can do so, but it is not the right way: `this.state.content = value; this.forceUpdate();` instead of `this.setState({content:value});` but this is not a good way!

Comment: Okay thank u, so what is the best way ? (Although I have to change all)

Comment: I guess, the best way try not using `this.state.property` after you call `setState` and try to find another way to write code. :)