# Dispatch action for onClick event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In react component I have made a function as

```
 handleClick(event, key, value) {
    event.preventDefault()
    this.setState({
      query:"",
      key:key,
      value:value
    });
    this.props.onClick(this.state);
    console.log("key...." + key   );
    console.log("val...." + value);
  }
```

this should be called when I am clicking a link

```
onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, {key}, {el}) }
```

Also using connect I am dispatching action as follows

```
export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({

  onClick: (query, key, value) => dispatch(onSearch(query,key, value)


  )
});
```

But on search method key and value are coming as undefined.But in handleClick function I am getting

```
key....[object Object]
val....[object Object]
```

Comment: Are `key` and `el` defined? Is the `onSearch` function defined?

Comment: Yes they are defined.I need to post that also?

Comment: No. But try `console.log({ key, val })`. That way you should be able to see the actual objects

Comment: check this answer for explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42593250/5185595

Comment: If I am using onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e, "js", "nmn") }, then also issue remains the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

key and value will be  undefined. You need to call props method on callback of setState because you will not get updated state value just after calling setState.

```
handleClick(event, key, value) {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
          query:"",
          key:key,
          value:value
        },()=>{

           this.props.onClick(this.state);
        console.log("key...." + key   );
        console.log("val...." + value);
    });

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way your calling the 'onClick' function is wrong, right now you are only passing one argument and not three.

It should be called like this

```
this.props.onClick(query, key, value);
```