# React not passing state to child via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I am trying to pass my parent `App` state to a child component `Chart`.

**App**

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        dataPoints: {
            '424353': {
                date: '10/10/2016',
                qty: '95'
            },
            '535332': {
                date: '10/11/2016',
                qty: '98'
            },
            '3453432': {
                date: '10/01/2017',
                qty: '94'
            }
        }
    };
    this.addPoint = this.addPoint.bind(this);
}

addPoint(dataPoint) {
    let dataPoints = {...this.state.dataPoints};
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    dataPoints[timestamp] = dataPoint;
    this.setState({ dataPoints: dataPoints });
    console.log('new state', this.state.dataPoints);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <Chart dataPoints={this.state.dataPoints} />
            <FormControl addPoint={this.addPoint} />
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Chart**

```
composeData() {
    Object
        .keys(this.props.dataPoints)
        .forEach(key => {
            ** do stuff **
        });

    return **stuff**;
}

componentWillUpdate() {
    this.composeData();
}
```

The `addPoint` method works, i.e. I can see in the React console that the new datapoint is added to the state. But it is not reflected in the `Chart` component. More oddly (to me) is the fact that when I've added a point, the `console.log` line in my `addPoint` method (above):

`console.log('new state', this.state.dataPoints)`

does not show the new data point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In add point

```
addPoint(dataPoint) {
    let dataPoints = {...this.state.dataPoints};
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    dataPoints[timestamp] = dataPoint;
    this.setState({ dataPoints: dataPoints });
    console.log('new state', this.state.dataPoints);
}
```

In the above code you do not see the updated value because setState takes time to mutate, You must log it in the setState call back

```
this.setState({ dataPoints: dataPoints }, function(){
    console.log('new state', this.state.dataPoints);
 });
```

And also in the Chart component you need to bind the composeData function if you are using `this.props` inside it like

```
composeData = () =>{
    Object
        .keys(this.props.dataPoints)
        .forEach(key => {
            ** do stuff **
        });

    return **stuff**;
}
```

However `componentWillMount` is only called once and hence you will want to call the `composeData` function from `componentWillReceiveProps` also like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
     this.composeData(nextProps)
}
componentWillMount() {
      this.composeData(this.props.dataPoints) 
 }
composeData(props){
        Object
            .keys(props.dataPoints)
            .forEach(key => {
                ** do stuff **
            });

        return **stuff**;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `setState` is `asynchronous`, use this you see the updated values:

```
this.setState({ dataPoints: dataPoints }, () => {
     console.log('new state', this.state.dataPoints);
});
```

Second thing is, whenever any change happen to `props` values, `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method will get called, do the computation in this method once you add the new item. Like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    console.log('update props values', newProps);
    Object
        .keys(newProps.dataPoints)
        .forEach(key => {
            ** do stuff **
        });

    return **stuff**;
}
```

Check this answer for complete explanation: [**why setState is asynchronous.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)