# setState is not updating state: ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I feel like I've tried everything under the sun here but must be missing something very obvious. In the `addItem() function` below, I am trying to push a new item into an array and update state, but no matter what I do state just won't change from the initial array.

When I console.log newListItems the new item is included, so everything up to that point is working, it's the actual state that won't update. What am I missing?

**addItem Method:**

```
addItem(text){
    var newListItems = this.state.listItems;
    newListItems.push(text);
    console.log(newListItems);

    this.setState = ({
        listItems : newListItems
    });

}
```

Also i am not getting any error message in console.

Full Code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
      
class ListItem extends Component{
  render(){
    return (<li>{this.props.title}</li>);
  }
}
     
class AddItem extends Component{

  handleClick(){
    this.props.addItem('blah');
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="additem">
        <input type="text" className="newitemname"/>
        <span className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Add item</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
    
    
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listItems : ['Wash the dishes','Do the laundry','Something else']
    };
  }

  addItem(text){
    var newListItems = this.state.listItems;
    newListItems.push(text);
    console.log(newListItems);
    this.setState = ({
      listItems : newListItems
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.listItems.map(function(item,index){
              return (
                  <ListItem key={index} title={item} />
              );
          })}
        </ul>
        <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}
    
    
export default App;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is, you are updating the `state` in a wrong way, Use this:

```
this.setState({
    listItems : newListItems
});
```

Instead of this:

```
this.setState = ({
    listItems : newListItems
});
```

**Reason:**

Because **[setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)** is a function not a variable, we need to call that to update the state values.

Check **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42593250/5185595)** for more details about **[setState behaviour](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate)**.

**Other Suggestions**:

When you assign any `array` to any variable, variable will only get the reference of `array`, means all the changes that you will perform, will directly applied on the original `array`. And its not a good idea to mutate the `state` variable directly, so first create the copy of the `array` by using `slice`, then use `push` to add the item in that. Like this:

```
var newListItems = this.state.listItems.slice();
newListItems.push(text);
this.setState({
     listItems : newListItems
});
```

As per [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state):

> Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
>   replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

Check the working example:

```js
class ListItem extends React.Component{

  render(){
    return (<li>{this.props.title}</li>);
  }

}


class AddItem extends React.Component{

  handleClick(){
    this.props.addItem(this.item.value);
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div className="additem">
        <input type="text" ref={item => this.item=item} className="newitemname"/>
        <span className="btn" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>Add item</span>
      </div>
    );
  }

}


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listItems : ['Wash the dishes','Do the laundry','Something else']
    };
  }

  addItem(text){
    var newListItems = this.state.listItems.slice();
    newListItems.push(text);
    this.setState({
      listItems : newListItems
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.state.listItems.map(function(item,index){
              return (
                  <ListItem key={index} title={item} />
              );
          })}
        </ul>
        <AddItem addItem={this.addItem.bind(this)} />
      </div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app' />
```

Comment: Oh my god. One equals sign has had me pulling my hair out for an hour! Thanks for the spot!

Comment: I would also add a `slice()` call after `var newListItems = this.state.listItems` in case somebody will switch to pure rendering.