# SetState the empty array with Json Response array of object?

Tags: reactjs

I have set the state of a array as [] empty, in componentDidMount i am getting the API Response.. now i want to set the state of the empty array with the new array of  json response how can i do this?

```
constructor(props)
{
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        categoryList : []
    }
}
componentDidMount()
{

    axios.get('http:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

    .then(res => 
    {
        this.setState = {
            categoryList : res.data.body.category_list(json path)
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('Error on Authentication' + error);
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with above code.

Comment: i want to set the state of categoryList as the Api Json Response.. just want to update the empty array with json response..

Comment: setState is a method, you need to call it with the object/updater function, remove `=`, like this: `this.setState({
            categoryList : res.data.body.category_list(json path)
        })`

Comment: ouch...sorry i didnt check the code properly...thank u

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setState is not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43323907/setstate-is-not-updating-state-reactjs/43323950#43323950)

Comment: @Ramya MiiM consider accepting any one of the answer whichever resolves your issue so that the thread will be closed and that will help future readers

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 this.setState({
    categoryList : res.data.body.category_list(json path)
 })
```

because `setState()` method accepts an object which will be merged with the current state.

Comment: couldnt understand

Comment: well then, this is just the way React team implements the `setState()` method. For more information, please read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand two things here

Below functionality is for initializing the states with initial values

```
this.state = {
  categoryList: []
}
```

To modify the categoryList state or any other state variable you need to use setState method like below. Keep in mind setState is a method

```
this.setState({
  categoryList : res.data.body.category_list(json path)
})
```