# maximum call stack error using setState in render function

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm starting to learn it but can't find a solution for this -> I have an input and when the value exceeds 20 characters I want a tooltip to appear with the full value as is typed. I have it all built and kind of working. Problem is that I get a maximum call stack error because the state is being changed on every key press - I'm not sure of the best/correct way to go about it... any help would be greatly appreciated

See my code below and [here is the pen](http://codepen.io/mike-grifin/pen/zwrNwE)

```
console.clear();

class Input extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <input
          className="main-input"
          onChange={this.props.onChange}
          placeholder={"Tell me something"}
          />
       </div>
    )
  };

}

class Tooltip extends React.Component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div
        className="tooltip"
        data-status={this.props.isShowing}>
        <p>{this.props.TooltipValue}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      message: '',
      isShowing: false
    }
  }

  onChange(e) {
      this.setState({
        message: e.target.value
      });
    }

  render(){
    const inputVal = (this.state.message.length);
    if(inputVal >= 20){
      this.setState({isShowing: true})
    } 
    // else {
    //   this.setState({isShowing: false})
    // }

    return(
      <div className="container">
        <Tooltip
          TooltipValue={this.state.message}
          isShowing={this.state.isShowing}
        />
        <Input onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    )
  }

}


ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('Main')
)
```

Comment: not sure it is good idea to change state inside render- I think render needs to be pure according to docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why maximum call stack error when using `setState` in `render` function ?

Because when we do `setState`, `React` trigger the re-rendering of the component, if you do `setstate` inside render then after `setState`, component will render again, again it will find `setState` again render, it will become a infinite loop, So never do any `setState` inside render method.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250) for more details about `setState` behaviour.

---

Instead of putting that check inside `render` method, put that inside `onChange` method, like this:

```
onChange(e) {
    const inputVal = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
        message: inputVal,
        isShowing : inputVal.length > 20 ? true : false
    });
}
```

And remove these lines:

```
if(inputVal >= 20){
    this.setState({isShowing: true})
} 
// else {
//   this.setState({isShowing: false})
// }
```

Or since the showing of `Tooltip` depends on the value of `input` element, you can avoid extra variable and directly check the length of input element with `Tooltip` property `isShowing`, like this:

```
<Tooltip
    TooltipValue={this.state.message}
    isShowing={this.state.message.length >= 20}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, very informative answer, I didn't know the setState re-renders the component. very helpful, thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

No need to use a separate state for the `tooltip` since it already depends on the state value you can do it like this

```
<Tooltip
      TooltipValue={this.state.message}
      isShowing={this.state.message.length > 20}  >
```

Also since you are using `setState` in the `render()` you are getting an error because `setState` triggers a re-render and thus beginning an infine loop as soon as you `if-condition` becomes true.

**[CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XRKQgz?editors=1111)**