# setState being called too late

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a text box auto focus.

However, I the `setState` is being called too late it seems.

It is being called within `Popup.show`. I created a button to console.log the state, and it does seem to be set to `true` but it must happen too late.

How can I get setState to be called as the `Popup.show` happens?

```
class Dashboard extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      focused: false,
    };
  }
  onClick = (event) => {
    console.log('Says focussed FALSE', this.state.focused)
    this.setState({ focused:true });
    Popup.show(<div>
      <SearchBar
        autoFocus
        focused={this.state.focused}
      />
      <button onClick={this.checkState}>It says TRUE here</button>
    </div>, 
     console.log('Says focussed FALSE still', this.state.focused),
   { animationType: 'slide-up'});
  };
  checkState = (e) =>{
    console.log(this.state)
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ padding: '0.15rem' }}>
      <Button onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}>Open & Focus</Button>
    </div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always remember that `setState` won't execute immediately. If you want `Popup.show()` after `setState`, you can use a callback:

```
this.setState({ focused: true }, () => {
  Popup.show(...)
})
```

And you are already using arrow functions, you don't need the `.bind(this)` in your render function.

Comment: This seems to have worked- but it is not focussing still. Is there another way to do this I can test?

Comment: This might related to the `Popup` and `SearchBar`

Answer (score 0):

`setState` doesn't immediate set the state

From: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate

> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.

Changing your `setState` to something like

```
this.setState({ focused: true }, () => {
    Popup.show(<div>
    <SearchBar
    autoFocus
    focused={this.state.focused}
    />
    <button onClick={this.checkState}>It says TRUE here</button>
    </div>)
});
```

Comment: I think this has worked, my the `focused={this.state.focused}` is still not reacting to. Is there any reason why this might be?

Comment: If you changed it to: `this.setState({ focused: true }, () => console.log(this.state.focused));` does it say true within the console? If it does, the issue may lie within your SearchBar