# When does React's setState change the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function `open()` in a child component which calls the parent's function `open()` through `props`, and it could be multiple times in a row.

the parent function contains this line

```
this.setState({numOpen: (++this.state.numOpen)});
```

This line works and updates the state at every increment.

But before, this line

```
this.setState({numOpen: (this.state.numOpen + 1)});
```

skipped over several increments and was breaking the program.

Does setState get called asynchronously? if not, what could be the reason for it?

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately

Comment: this a good article https://medium.com/@mweststrate/3-reasons-why-i-stopped-using-react-setstate-ab73fc67a42e

Comment: thanks @MayankShukla that answered my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: @VikramSaini that's a great article, thanks

Answer (score 4):

As the Duplicate answer by @MayankShukla indicates, `setState is asynchronous`,

however Adding an explanation and a corrected approach

In the below case:

```
this.setState({numOpen: (++this.state.numOpen)});
```

You are mutating the state directly and then setting the value and hence it works, but is not the right way to do it

In the second case

```
this.setState({numOpen: (this.state.numOpen + 1)});
```

`setState` is adding the value to the current state as you experience it leads to unexpected behaviour due to its asynchronous nature.

The correct way to do it is to use the `prevState` callback approach

```
 this.setState((prevState) => ({numOpen: (prevState.numOpen + 1)});
```