# React Native: I'm dynamically setting options of one drop down depending on another drop down value selection. But this.setlection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native so this.setstate method is not predictable for me.

I'm selecting a list of Venue on dropdown 1
according to the venue , the number of available days must be shown as options on the second dropdown.
and similarly according to the second one i have to set timeslots avaiable on the third dropdown

the 2nd to 3rd dropdown works fine for me
but when i select the venue on the first dropdown the 2nd one does not updates. this .setstate is working late there

if i select the venue once more the previously selected days loads not the current one. like setstate method is lagging one step behind

Must be the way i wrote the code , 
I am open to corrections, new structure of coding , anything
but very much in need to get this work

```
onVenueSelect(index,value){
    var props=this.props;
    console.log('On venue Select................................')
    console.log('index'+index)
    console.log('value'+value)
    console.log(this.state.venue_id_array[index])
    props.getFixtureSlots(this.state.venue_id_array[index], this.state.game_type, this.state.game);
    this.setState({selected_venue_id:this.state.venue_id_array[index]})

    var days=[];
    var timeslots=props.GETFIXTURETIME.timeslot;
    for(var i in timeslots){
      days.push(timeslots[i].day_of_week);
    }
    this.setDay_array(days);
    this.refs.modal_dayselect.select(-1);
    this.setState({selected_venue:value});
  }

  onDaySelect(index,value){
    this.refs.modal_hrsselect.select(-1);
    this.props.getFixtureSlots(this.state.selected_venue_id, this.state.game_type, this.state.game);
    var props=this.props;
    this.setState({selected_day_no:this.state.day_no_array[index]})
    console.log(this.state.day_no_array[index])
    this.setState({selected_day:value})

  }

  render_center_selection(){

      return(
        this.props.selecteddays_array.map((a, i) => {
          return( <View key={i} style={{ height:40, borderBottomWidth:2, borderBottomColor: '#ededed' }}>{
                    <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
                      <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                        <ModalDropdown 
                            style={styles.selection}
                            defaultValue='Venue'
                            textStyle={{width:200,fontSize:20,textAlign:'center',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            dropdownStyle={styles.dropdownstyle}
                            dropdownTextStyle={{width:350,fontSize:20,textAlign:'center',backgroundColor: '#FDD60B',}}
                            options={this.state.venue_name_array}
                            onSelect={(index,value)=>{this.onVenueSelect(index,value)}}/>
                        <ModalDropdown 
                            ref="modal_dayselect"
                            style={styles.dayselection}
                            defaultValue='Day'
                            textStyle={{width:50,fontSize:15,textAlign:'center',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            dropdownStyle={styles.daydropdownstyle}
                            dropdownTextStyle={{width:50,fontSize:15,textAlign:'center',backgroundColor: '#FDD60B',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            options={this.state.day_array}
                            onSelect={(index,value)=>{this.onDaySelect(index,value)}}/>
                        <ModalDropdown 
                            ref="modal_hrsselect"
                            style={styles.dayselection}
                            defaultValue='HRS'
                            textStyle={{width:50,fontSize:15,textAlign:'center',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            dropdownStyle={styles.daydropdownstyle}
                            dropdownTextStyle={{width:50,fontSize:15,textAlign:'center',backgroundColor: '#FDD60B',color: '#7070D8'}}
                            options={this.state.hrs_array}
                            onSelect={(index,value)=>{this.setState({selected_hr:value})}}/>
                      </View>

                    </View>
                  }</View>);                           
        }) 
      );
  }
```

Comment: These two answers will help you understand what the problem is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44492678/when-does-reacts-setstate-change-the-state/44493095#44493095 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41278385/this-setstate-doesnt-update-value/41278440#41278440

Comment: Yeah, but now it updates the value sometimes, sometimes does not.           
  thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

First thing you have to do is to remove all `console.log` statements from your code. It really helpful but slows down the app rendering/refreshing rate.

Second thing and the most important thing is to consolidate state setting calls. ie, you only need one `setState` call inside one action. For every `setState` call the app re-renders the parts which uses that changed state. So, update multiple states at once otherwise it will not be detected by the react.