# Update state value in componentWillreceiveProps

Tags: reactjs

```
class Filters extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 0 };
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    nextProps.dataAsProp.map(data => {
      if (data.productList.length == 0)
       this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
     });

}
```

---

How do I update the value of count for each data who's produclist is a null array. It only prints one. It doesn't count for all the data in dataAsProp.

Comment: everytime the parent rerenders the componentWillReceiveProps of child is called, so This what mayank suggested may not work properly, could you explain you usecase a little

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason is setState is asynchronous so we can't predict the updated value in loop iteration.

Changes:

1.Instead of doing setState multiple times, first calculate the value and then at the end update the state count value once.

2.Use `forEach` instead of `map`.

Write it like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    /*put the check here, perform this operation only when there a change between nextProps and prev props values*/

     let count = 0;
     nextProps.dataAsProp.forEach(data => {
        if (data.productList.length == 0)
            count++;
     });
     this.setState({ count });
}
```

Check this [answer for difference between forEach and map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34426458/js-learning-difference-between-foreach-and-map).

check this answer for more details about asynchronous behaviour of setState :

[Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)