# Calling functions from a function being called on clicking button in react

Tags: reactjs

I have something like this. I am calling _onButtonClickDryRun on clicking a button, which inturn calls  another function on being clicked. In first function I am changing the state and in second function I want to use the changed state. However I see that `_onafterButtonClick` does not see the effect of the new state changed by `this.setState` statement

```
_onButtonClickDryRun = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      name: data.name,
    });
  this._onafterButtonClick(true); 
  };

_onafterButtonClick = (isDryRun: boolean) => {
 //makes use of this.state.name;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: use callback and write it like this: `_onButtonClickDryRun = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      name: data.name,
    }, 
    () => { 
    this._onafterButtonClick(true); 
   })
};`

Comment: you got the solution or still facing the issue?

Comment: Yup that worked for me !