# Why React component doesn't render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux, react-alt

I am making simple react app. I need to make an order. For that order I need a list of all users and products.I have `CreateOrder` component which has 2 variables in its `state` - `users` and `products`. Here is the constructor

```
this.state.orders = OrderStore.getState()
this.state.products = ProductStore.getState()
this.state.users = UserStore.getState()
this.onOrderChange = this.onOrderChange.bind(this)
this.onProductChange = this.onProductChange.bind(this)
this.onUserChange = this.onUserChange.bind(this)
this.createOrder = this.createOrder.bind(this)
this.renderProducts = this.renderProducts.bind(this)
this.renderUsers = this.renderUsers.bind(this)
this.users = []
this.products = []
```

As you can see I am using 3 stores and therefore 3 functions for updating these stores. After that I have 2 functions for rendering products and users. Those functions take all products and users from their respective variable and create an array of `option` tags to be used `<select>`. Those arrays are stored in `this.users` and `this.products` so that I can use them.

Here is the code in `renderUsers` and `renderProducts`

```
renderUsers(){
    this.users = this.state.users.users.map((user, i) => (
        <option
          key={i + 1}
          value={user}>
          {user.username}
        </option>
      )
    )
    console.log(this.users)
  }
  renderProducts(){
    this.products = this.state.products.products.map((product, i) => (
        <option
          key={i + 1}
          value={product}>
          {product.name}
        </option>
      )
    )
    console.log(this.products)
  }
```

I can't see much of a difference between the two. After the arrays are made and filled with `option` tags I use `console.log` to see the result. Here is a picture of what actually

[image]
As you can see there are 2 arrays of objects and each object is react component as expected.

When I render `CreateOrder` I use `this.products` and `this.users` to be rendered and at first they are empty. Then when something changes in the stores (they are filled with all products and users) the functions `renderUsers` and `renderProducts` are executed and therefore the arrays are filled with data. When this happens I expect the view to be updated.

Now the problem - When this happens and `this.products` is being updated the view actually changes and is actually updated with a list of all products. However - using the same logic and the same functions and code - the users are not being updated. They stay the same. Even though I have them as elements in an array and I call this array in `render` they are not being updated.

To add some information here is my whole `CreateOrder` file.

```
 /**
 * Created by PC on 01-Aug-17.
 */
import React from 'react'
import OrderActions from '../actions/OrderActions'
import ProductActions from '../actions/ProductActions'
import ProductStore from '../stores/ProductStore'
import UserActions from '../actions/UserActions'
import UserStore from '../stores/UserStore'
import OrderStore from '../stores/OrderStore'

import Select from './sub-components/SelectComponent'
import Input from './sub-components/InputComponent'

export default class CreateOrder extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {}
    this.state.orders = OrderStore.getState()
    this.state.products = ProductStore.getState()
    this.state.users = UserStore.getState()
    this.onOrderChange = this.onOrderChange.bind(this)
    this.onProductChange = this.onProductChange.bind(this)
    this.onUserChange = this.onUserChange.bind(this)
    this.createOrder = this.createOrder.bind(this)
    this.renderProducts = this.renderProducts.bind(this)
    this.renderUsers = this.renderUsers.bind(this)
    this.users = []
    this.products = []
  }
  componentDidMount () {
    OrderStore.listen(this.onOrderChange)
    ProductStore.listen(this.onProductChange)
    UserStore.listen(this.onUserChange)
    ProductActions.getAllProducts()
    UserActions.getAllUsers()

  }
  componentWillUnmount () {
    OrderStore.unlisten(this.onOrderChange)
    UserStore.unlisten(this.onUserChange)
    ProductStore.unlisten(this.onProductChange)

  }
  onOrderChange (state) {
    this.setState({orders:state})
  }
  onProductChange(state) {
    this.setState({products:state})
    this.renderProducts()
  }
  onUserChange(state){
    this.setState({users:state})
    this.renderUsers()
  }
  createOrder (event) {
    event.preventDefault()

      let data = {}
      data['username'] = this.state.orders.username
      data['productName'] = this.state.orders.product.name
      data['productPrice'] = this.state.orders.product.price
      data['quantity'] = this.state.orders.quantity

      OrderActions.addOrder(data)
  }
  renderUsers(){
    this.users = this.state.users.users.map((user, i) => (
        <option
          key={i + 1}
          value={user}>
          {user.username}
        </option>
      )
    )
    console.log(this.users)
  }
  renderProducts(){
    this.products = this.state.products.products.map((product, i) => (
        <option
          key={i + 1}
          value={product}>
          {product.name}
        </option>
      )
    )
    console.log(this.products)
  }
  render () {

    return (
      <div>
        <div className='has-error'>
          {this.state.orders.error}
        </div>
        <div className='has-success'>
          {this.state.orders.success}
        </div>
        <form>
          <select>{this.users}</select>
          <select>{this.products}</select>

          <div className="inputField">
            <label htmlFor='title'>Quantity</label>
            <Input
              type='number'
              name='price'
              id='price'
              placeholder='Price'
              onChange={OrderActions.handleQuantityChange}
              value={this.state.quantity}/>
          </div>
          <input type='submit' onClick={this.createOrder.bind(this)} value='Create Order'/>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the actual cause of the problem but i think this is related to async behaviour of setState, we can't expect the updated state value just after the setState.

Check this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)** for more details about async behaviour of setState.

**Solution:**

Storing the ui component in state variable or in global variable is not a good idea, all ui logic should be inside render method, so instead of storing the options in global variable, directly return from that function.

Whenever we do `setState` react will re-render the component and update the ui with new data.

**Step1 -** Use these methods, removed another function calling:

```
onProductChange(state) {
    this.setState({products:state})
}

onUserChange(state){
    this.setState({users:state})
}
```

**Step2** - Use these methods to render the options:

```
renderUsers(){
    if(!this.state.users.users) return null;

    return this.state.users.users.map((user, i) => (
        <option
          key={i + 1}
          value={user}>
          {user.username}
        </option>
      )
    )
}

renderProducts(){
    if(!this.state.products.products) return null;

    return this.state.products.products.map((product, i) => (
        <option
          key={i + 1}
          value={product}>
          {product.name}
        </option>
      )
    )
}
```

**Step3 -** Call these functions from render to create options:

```
 <select>{this.renderUsers()}</select>
 <select>{this.renderProducts()}</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous. Try putting your `this.renderUsers();` in the `componentWillUpdate` lifecycle method.

> componentWillUpdate() is invoked immediately before rendering when new props or state are being received. Use this as an opportunity to perform preparation before an update occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.

You could also use the `callback` argument of [setState(updater, [callback])](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).