# setState into 2D array - ReactJS

Tags: arrays, reactjs, collections

I have a 2D array and I need to update it in componentWillReceiveProps but it doesn't get updated.

This is my state;

```
this.state={
            conditionRaw:[[]]
        }
```

And this is componentWillReceiveProps method;

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        let rules = {conditionRaw:[[]]};
        if (nextProps.rootObject._id !== ""){
            rules["conditionRaw"] = nextProps.rootObject.conditionRaw
            this.setState({conditionRaw: rules.conditionRaw})
            console.log("DENEMEBİRLKİ", this.state.conditionRaw)
        }

    }
```

My nextProps come filled but I reckon I'm failing at setState.

Comment: `this.setState({conditionRaw: rules.conditionRaw}, () => {console.log(this.state.conditionRaw);});` what does this say?

Comment: An empty array is returned @Nocebo

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your console log:

```
console.log("DENEMEBİRLKİ", this.state.conditionRaw)
```

might be misleading, since `setState()` is asynchronous. Try this instead:

```
this.setState({conditionRaw: rules.conditionRaw}, () => {console.log(this.state.conditionRaw);});
```

Comment: Wow, yeah it returns filled now.So this means I updated my state successfully, right?

Comment: Yeah, `setState` is asynchronous. Always use this callback function to check wheter or not it changed

Comment: Thanks a lot! I can't mark your answer now. After 10  minutes, I'll do it.

Comment: No problem! Thanks

Comment: @BurakULU would you be so kind to mark my answer :)