# how to clear the react state array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux

How to clear the existing data in react state variable (Array) and assign another array to it. I have try below thing but it doesn't works.

```
    itemsChanged(items) {
        this.setState({item : []})    //item is my state variable
        this.setState({item : items})
        console.log("ITEMS : ",this.state.item)   //this  will not print the updated value
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: setting `this.setState({ item: items })` should already override the existing array if it is a different collection of items. `setState` is asynchronous so your console may be firing before the action is actually completed

Comment: Pl go through this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250

Comment: to check the result state you need to move the console.log in the handler like this : `this.setState({item : []}, function() {console.log("ITEMS : ",this.state.item)})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to assign an empty array first. Just pass the new array to it. The only reason why it's not working is that `setState` is an asynchronous call. Use it like this

```
 this.setState({item : items}, () => console.log("ITEMS : ",this.state.item) )
```

Comment: @narenmnp Please accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

According to [React's docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

If you want to check your state value after `setState`, you should do like:

`this.setState({item : items}, () => console.log(this.state.item));`

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an async method. So, when you print it on console, It still can be updating. You can use console log before return render.

```
...

render(){
  console.log("ITEMS : ",this.state.item);
  return (<div>...</div>)
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

As they describe:

```
setState(updater, [callback])
```

so that may suggest it is not a synchronous operation.

Use:

```
itemsChanged(items) {
  var me = this;

  me.setState({item : items}, function(){
         console.log("ITEMS : ", me.state.item);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should understand about `setState` is that it works asynchronously. If you try to `console.log` the state directly after calling `setState`, you won't see any changes yet.

You also don't have to clear out the array by calling `setState` with an empty array--you can just replace the current array with the new array.

`this.setState({ items: newItems });`

If you want to log the change, I'd suggest trying to do it in the component's `componentShouldUpdate` method.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is an async function，if you are writting the code as that:

```
this.setState({xxState})
console.log(this.state.xxState)
```

The program will execute the `console.log` first，so you should write as that：

```
this.setState（｛xxx｝，（）=> ｛
    console.log（this.state.....）
｝）
```

And it will be work well.