# Render function does not update the view after state update

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following constructor

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.renderConversations = this.renderConversations.bind(this);
    this.startConversation = this.startConversation.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      conversationArray: []
    }
}
```

In function `startConversation` I update the state variable.

```
startConversation(conversationObject) {
    let currentResponse = conversationObject["responses"];
    let thisResponse = currentResponse[Math.floor(Math.random() * currentResponse.length)];

    this.state.conversationArray.push(thisResponse);
    this.renderConversations();

}
```

In the function `renderConversations` , I'm doing the following:

```
renderConversations(){
    let conversationContent = this.state.conversationArray.map((conv, i) => {
      return <View key={i} style={[globalStyle.conversationContainer,globalStyle.shadow]}><Text style= {globalStyle.conversationText}>{ conv }</Text></View>                            
    })
    return conversationContent
}
```

Finally, in the render function, I render `{this.renderConversations()}`. Now `startConversation` is triggered on a button click.
But each time I update the state variable the component is not updated, What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per **[DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state)**:

> Never mutate this.state directly, use setState for that, Treat this.state as if it were
>   immutable.

---

You are updating the state in a wrong way, "Never mutate the state value directly always use [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to update it". When we use [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) react automatically re-render the component with update state value.

Write it like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
     conversationArray: [...prevState.conversationArray, thisResponse]
}))
```

Another issue is *setState is async*, we can not expect the update state value just after the setState, so use callback method of [setState](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and call `renderConversations` inside that.

Like this:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({...}), () => this.renderConversations())
```

Read this answer for more detail about **[async behaviour of setState](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)**.

**Suggestion:** All the ui logic should be inside render method, so if you want to create ui dynamically call that `renderConversations` from render.

Comment: Works prefectly. Thanks for that extra tip. :)