# Cannot update state with spread operator in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, spread-syntax

I'm new to React, and I just can't figure out how to push new elements inside an array defined into state, using the spread operator.
The purpose is to obtain an array containing a sequence of different numbers, the code is the following:

```
getSequence = () => {
    let n = 0;

    while ( n < 3 ) {
      let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      let exists = this.state.sequence.indexOf(number);

      if ( exists < 0 ) {
        this.setState({
          sequence: [...this.state.sequence, number]
        });

        n++;
      }
    }
  }
```

The event is triggered by onClick event, but on each click the array will be updated with only one number.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: `setState` is an Async function, I don't think it works as you expected inside that while loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes:

1- [setState is async](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), so it will not work as you are expecting. As per DOC:

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall.

2- Using `setState` in loop is not a good idea, create the array of three numbers first then simply merge that into state array.

3- If new state value is dependent on previous state then use updater function instead of `this.state` inside `setState`.

Check this answer: [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)

Write it like this:

```
getSequence = () => {
    let n = 0, arr = [];

    while ( n < 3 ) {
        let number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
        let exists = this.state.sequence.indexOf(number);

        if ( exists < 0 ) {
            arr.push(number);
            n++;
        }
    }

    this.setState(prevState => ({
        sequence: [...prevState.sequence, ...arr]
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it works like a charm! The problem was indeed that setState() is an async function.