# Does render get called immediately after setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following function:

```
onSelectDepartment = (evt) => {
    const department = evt.target.value;
    const course = null;

    this.setState({ department, course });

    this.props.onChange({ name: 'department', value: department });
    this.props.onChange({ name: 'course', value: course });

    if (department) this.fetch(department);
};
```

The question is, after the `setState` function get called, the `render` function on the component will be executed immediately or after function call is finished?

Comment: Let's say that the `props.onChange` will trigger a re-render of the parent and the child, then you will most likely end up with a single render instead of 3. But it is not guaranteed as @MayankShukla writes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> render function on the component will be executed immediately or after
>   function call is finished?

No one can take the guarantee of when that render function will get called, because setState is async, when we call setState means we ask react to update the ui with new state values (request to call the render method), but exactly at what time that will happen, we never know.

Have a look what [react doc says about setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user
>   interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> Think of **setState() as a request rather than an immediate command** to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. **React
>   does not guarantee** that the state changes are applied immediately.

Check this answer for more details about async behavior of setState: [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking execute some piece of code only once the setState is completed you can use below format.

```
this.setState({
   flag: true
}, ()=> {
         // any code you want to execute only after the newState has taken effect. 
         })
```

This is the way to make sure your desired piece of code only runs on the new state.