# setState Concat storing/returning only First value-- React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

While setting state , Even-though length of array is 9, Its displaying only first value. I'm not sure where its going wrong.

```
_GoTown = () => {
    if (this.state.stTownRawData == '') {
        alert(i18n.t('plsseltown'));
    }
    else {
        this.setState({ stAtmList: [] });
        var rartown = this.state.stTownRawData;
        for (i = 0; i < rartown.length; i++) {
            console.log(i);
            this.setState({ stAtmList: this.state.stAtmList.concat({ key: i, town: i18n.t('town') + rartown[i].town, address: i18n.t('add') + rartown[i].addressLine1, lat: rartown[i].latitude, long: rartown[i].longitude, icon: require('../../resources/toolbar/atm.png') }) });
        }
        console.log(rartown);
    }
}
```

> Console.log(i) returns values from 0 to 8. I'm not sure why setState is  populating stAtmList with only first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is async so even if you set the value as `[]` in first line, it's 
not necessary that in next line you will get the updated value.

---

Issue is, You are updating the state value in loop, so there is no guarantee that in next iteration state will have the updated value. Use a variable and push all the values inside that, and update the state at the end means when for loop ends.

You need to write it like this:

```
_GoTown = () => {
    if (this.state.stTownRawData == '') {
        alert(i18n.t('plsseltown'));
    }
    else {
        let stAtmList = []
        let rartown = this.state.stTownRawData;
        for (let i = 0; i < rartown.length; i++) {
            stAtmList.push({ key: i, town: i18n.t('town') + rartown[i].town, address: i18n.t('add') + rartown[i].addressLine1, lat: rartown[i].latitude, long: rartown[i].longitude, icon: require('../../resources/toolbar/atm.png') }) });
        }
        this.setState({ stAtmList });
    }
}
```

Check this answer for more details:

[Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)

Comment: Thank you. Understood setstate is async process. Working Fine.