# React js state is not updating in side ajax block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, reactjs

```
$.post('/api/settings/exicution', data, (result)  => {
            $("#errorBox").hide();
            $("#successBox").show();

            this.setState({
                isSavedInDB: true
            });
}).fail((response)  => {
    console.log('error  ' + error);
    $("#errorBox").show();
    $("#successBox").hide();

    this.setState({
        isSavedInDB: false
    });
});

console.log(this.state.isSavedInDB);

if(this.state.isSavedInDB) {
    showconfrim("Do you want to add more Projects ?",e => this.addNewProject());
}
```

i am trying to update `isSavedInDB` value inside success response of ajax call. but it is not update inside the success block and error block.
so can any ane help me on this.

i have decleared `isSavedInDB` in side my `constructor` `state` block

Comment: api call will be asyn so put the condition and console.log inside success block, otherwise it will get expected before you get the data. also setState is asyn so you can't expcet the updated value just after the setState.

Comment: `$.post` is async. `setState` is async. You can't expect state to be updated immediatelly after you sent a request.

Comment: so where should i update the state ?

Comment: @SangramBadi put the if condition inside a separate function and then use that function as a setState callback, like this: `this.setState({...}, () => this.functionName())`.

Comment: let me check your answer

Comment: @MayankShukla thanks for your reply. it's working

Comment: @SangramBadi check this answer, why setState callback is required: [**LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)