# React. How to update the state with previous state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to update the state, based on previous state `(array of objects)` with the new incoming values in fase of `object`. But for some reasons it does not happen...

What is I'm doing wrong? My code:

```
   handleCommentSubmit = (newEmployer) => {
       console.log('handleCommentSubmit BEFORE', this.state.employers, newEmployer); // array(5)
       this.setState((prevState, newEmployer) => { 
         employers: prevState.employers + newEmployer
       });
       console.log('handleCommentSubmit AFTER', this.state.employers); // still array(5)
   }
```

My log:

```
handleCommentSubmit BEFORE (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}], newEmployer: {first_name: "sdfsdf", last_name: "sdfsdf", birth_date: "123123-03-12", salary: "123123123"}
handleCommentSubmit AFTER (6) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

Comment: Whats wrong with just .push'ing to state.employers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [setState not updating state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)

Answer (score -7, accepted):

`this.setState` should receive object as an argument. Not a function.
You could easily use `this.state`:

```
handleCommentSubmit = (newEmployer) => {
  this.setState({ 
    employers: this.state.employers.concat(newEmployer)
  });
}
```

Comment: -1. `this.setState` *does* accept a function as an argument, see [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: setting state may be asychroneous, this solution has a chance to cause problems in certain cases. View my solution with explanation below.

Comment: This answer is wrong. It is advised to use the function parameter to update state when the new state depends on the previous state--given the asynchronous nature of `setState`.

Comment: Please don't provide wrong information if you are not sure about it. setState accepts both object as well as function, it depends on your usage what you want to use at the moment.

Answer (score 9):

Changes:

1- `setState` is async so use callback to check the updated value.

2- Use `[].concat` to push a new value in array, `+` will not work.

3- You are not returning the `object` from the updater function.

Write it like this:

```
handleCommentSubmit = (newEmployer) => {
    this.setState((prevState, newEmployer) => ({
        employers: prevState.employers.concat(newEmployer)
    }), () => {
        console.log('handleCommentSubmit AFTER', this.state.employers);
    }); 
}
```

Check this answer for more details:

[Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)

Comment: See React's page : https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

To further enhance the relevance of @Mayank's solution.

Answer (score 3):

If your `employers` is an Array you can use `spread operator` in setState:

`[...prevState.employers, newEmployer]`

but you don't need `prevState` at all. You can just:

```
this.setState({ 
         employers: [...this.state.employers, newEmployer]
       });
```

Answer (score 2):

if you call the setState it won't update immediately in the next line. It will update after the render method gets called.
If you want to see the updatedState you can write a callback function in the setState like this.

```
this.setState((prevState, newEmployer) => { 
         employers: prevState.employers + newEmployer
       }, () => console.log('UpdatedState', this.state.employers));
```