# Is this.setState() of react.js synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please look into the following code. I have tried calling `setState` one below the other. It looks like `count` which is returned from the second call of `setState` is always set to `this.state.count`. Here, It's always assigned with `3`

```
    class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.handleReset = this.handleReset.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            count : 0
        };
    }

    handleReset() {
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                count: 1
            }
        });
        this.setState(() => {
            return {
                count: 3
            }
        });
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div> 
                <h1>Count:{this.state.count}</h1>
                <button onClick={this.handleReset}>reset</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
  }
  ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: check the [**doc**](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250)

Answer (score 1):

According to React docs, it can be async.

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance. Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state

[(original source, and correct code example)](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous. You can pass callback as second argument and see the updated state.

```
this.setState({ count: 5 }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.count) // 5
})
```

Comment: Then, why do I get the `this.state.count` always set to `3` which is returned from the second call for setState() api

Comment: @Prem because it was called last

Comment: When two asynchronous calls are invoked one below the other, is there any guarantee for the order of execution?

Comment: @Prem, sure if you synchronously add it to the stack. But to be honest, I am not sure how react implements it