# Correct variable syntax in this.state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set variable in this.state

My variable is defined as VariableName+"Error"

This code works well, but it isnt good to mutate state directly:

```
this.state[VariableName+"Error"] = "";
```

My bad try to mutate state in this.state which does not work:

```
this.setState({
      VariableNameError: ""
  })
```

Comment: `this.setState({ [VariableName+"Error"]: '' })`

Comment: @MayankShukla Doesnt work for me

Comment: can you show exactly what u r trying?

Comment: this.state.validationRules.map((rule, i) =>{
    
   var propertyName = rule["a:PropertyName"][0];
  
 
 this.setState({
      [propertyName+"Error"]: ""
  })         In propertyName is string with VariableName

Comment: 'a:PropertyName' is fixed string or `PropertyName` is a variable there?

Comment: It is string. thank you @MayankShukla you have solved this. I didnt know that if i once use set.state i cant mutate directly in next code.

Comment: check this answer for more details about [**async nature of setState**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250#42593250), also better to not use setState in loop, write it like this: `let obj = {};

this.state.validationRules.forEach((rule, i) => { 
 var propertyName = rule["a:PropertyName"][0]; 
 obj[propertyName+'Error'] = '';
})

this.setState(obj) ;`