# React updated state value form child doesn't reach parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, parent-child, console.log

From My parent component I give an array of time slots to a child component in that component I display the time slots and when a time slot is clicked it should give that value back to the parent component.

But something goes wrong. When I log everything. The clicked value does log but the same value that  should be passed to the parent doesn't log

Logs

[image]

I also noticed that the parent log (the one that doesn't show a value) comes first. But it shouldn't log this one first

Child component

```
class ShowAvailableTimeslots extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            size : 5,
            selectedSlotValue:"",
        }
        this.handleTimeSlotClick = this.handleTimeSlotClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleTimeSlotClick(timeslot){
        this.setState({
            selectedSlotValue: timeslot
        })
        this.props.onClick(this.state.selectedSlotValue)
        console.log('time slot value', timeslot)
    
    }
    render() {
       var timeSlotArr =  this.props.timeSlots.slice(0,this.state.size);
        return (
            <React.Fragment>


                {
                    timeSlotArr.map(timeSlot => <a className="timeslot btn "key={timeSlot} onClick={() => {this.handleTimeSlotClick(timeSlot)}}>{timeSlot}</a>)

                }

            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default ShowAvailableTimeslots
```

parent component

```
class UpdateAppointment extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            startDate: new Date(),
            selectedService: "",
            selectedClient: "",
            start: "",
            end: "",
            clientId: "",
            serviceId: "",

            id: this.props.calendar.id,
            selectedDate: this.props.calendar.start,

            updateAppointmentStart: "",
            updateAppointmentEnd: "",
            updateStartDate: "",
            updateDate: "",

            buttonIsDisabled: true,
            appointmentHasOverlap: false,
            updatedView: false,
            newServiceSelected: false,
           

            AvailabletimeSlots:[],
        };
        this.openDeleteAppointment = this.openDeleteAppointment.bind(this);
        this.handleDateSelect = this.handleDateSelect.bind(this);
        this.handleServiceSelect = this.handleServiceSelect.bind(this);
    };
    handleDateSelect(date) {
        this.setState({
            selectedDate: Moment(date),
        })  
    }
    handleServiceSelect = (selectedServiceObj, buttonState, timeSlots) => {

        this.setState({
            newServiceSelected: true,
            AvailabletimeSlots: timeSlots,

        });
        console.log("available timeslots: " , timeSlots)
        if (buttonState) {
            this.setState({
                buttonIsDisabled: buttonState,
                appointmentHasOverlap: buttonState,
            });

        } else {

            this.setState({
                selectedService: selectedServiceObj,
                serviceId: selectedServiceObj.id,
                start: this.props.calendar.start,
                end: this.props.calendar.start.clone().add(selectedServiceObj.hours, 'hours').add(selectedServiceObj.minutes, 'minutes'),
                buttonIsDisabled: buttonState,
                appointmentHasOverlap: buttonState,
                newServiceSelected: true,

            });
        }

    };
    getSelectedTimeslot(selectedSlotValue){
        console.log("seletedStorValue", selectedSlotValue)
        // console.log("selectedDate", this.state.selectedDate)
        // this.setState({
        //     // updateAppointmentStart: Moment(`${this.state.selectedDate} ${selectedSlotValue}`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
        // })
    }

    handleClientSelect = (selectedClientObj) => {

        this.setState({ selectedClient: selectedClientObj, clientId: selectedClientObj.id });
    };


    render() {

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="customModal">
                    <div className="modal-container">

                        <div className="update">
                            <div className="update-time">
                                <label>Selected date: </label>
                                <p>{this.state.selectedDate.format('dddd, MMMM Do YYYY')}</p>
                                <DatePicker
                                    selected={this.state.selectedDate.toDate()}
                                    onChange={this.handleDateSelect}
                                    inline
                                />
                               
                            </div>
                            <div className="update-service-client">
                                <ServiceSearch onChange={this.handleServiceSelect} serviceId={this.state.viewServiceId} start={this.state.selectedDate}  searchGoal='update'/>
                                <div>
                                {this.state.newServiceSelected ? <ShowAvailableTimeslots onClick={this.getSelectedTimeslot} timeSlots={this.state.AvailabletimeSlots}/>  : ''}
                                </div>
                                <ClientSearch onChange={this.handleClientSelect} clientId={this.state.viewClientId} />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                   
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default UpdateAppointment
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: `this.setState` is asynchronous, so accessing `this.state.selectedSlotValue` immediately after you update it with `this.setState` will return the old value.

Comment: @goto1 Thank you the link indeed helped with a part of my problem. I implemented the suggested changes that were provided in the above link. The logs now show in the order that It should show but I'm still not getting the clicked time slot value in my parent component only in child component

Comment: Show how you implemented `handleTimeSlotClick` inside the `child` component after the fix. And I am assuming `getSelectedTimeslot`is the one where you're not seeing the updated value?