# Basics implementation example of useState Hooks in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

We know that the **useState** hook is used for managing state within functional components in ReactJs.

So, for learning purposes I was implementing the example of the useState hook (snippet is given below)  wherein I have taken an array with some initial value and I need to update the array and display the whole updated array in the browser whenever I clicked on the button. I tried with the below snippet but didn't get the expected result.

Problem: When I click the button for first time it will add the new element in the array but after clicking the button for two or more times it only overrides the last element.

Expected Result: New elements should be added in the array rather than overriding the last element in the array.

I definitely missing any logic or any important concept of useState hook here in this example. Please help me to understand more on react Hooks.

```js
const {useState} = React;

const Example = () => {
    const array = [1,2,3] ;
    const [newArray,setNewArray] = useState(array);
    const [newElement,setElement]= useState(array[array.length-1]);

    const handleBoth = () => {
        setElement(prev => prev + 1);
        setNewArray([...array,newElement]);
    }

    const mapping = newArray.map(element => <li> No. {element}</li>)    

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {mapping}
            </ul>
            <button onClick={handleBoth}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the state `newArray` not the `array` for the `map` implementation. `array` will reinitialize to `[1,2,3]` on every render. In fact, you should just move the `array` constant outside of the component

```js
const {useState} = React;
const array = [1,2,3];

const Example = () => {
    const [newArray,setNewArray] = useState(array);
    const [newElement,setElement]= useState(array[array.length-1]+1);

    const handleBoth = () => {
        setElement(prev => prev + 1);
        setNewArray([...newArray,newElement]);
    }

    const mapping = newArray.map(element => <li> No. {element}</li>)    

    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
                {mapping}
            </ul>
            <button onClick={handleBoth}>Add</button>
        </div>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Could you explain more about what was happening before? So next time I'll aware that something is misplaced.

Comment: Yes, the issue is primarily regarding this statement that you had `setNewArray([...array,newElement]);`. Every re-render, React will go through the entire component, so `array` gets initialized back to `[1,2,3]` again. So when you are calling that `setNewArray` - everytime you call it, it simply doing this: `setNewArray([1,2,3,newElement]);` ... versus when using state - that value is not reinitalized everytime the component re-renders, it is only initially initialized when you call `useState`, so the state values will persist on renders

Comment: yeah, I clearly understood now what has happened before. Small doubt why did you add +1 here `useState(array[array.length-1]+1);`?

Comment: Oh ok, your `array` is `[1,2,3]`. Therefore `array[array.length-1]` = 3. But when you append to the list you don't want to append 3 because this will happen --> `[1,2,3,3]`. You want to add 4. So that is the correct equation of `array[array.length-1]+1`

Comment: You have setted the newElement `setElement(prev => prev + 1);` just before setting the newArray `setNewArray([...newArray,newElement]);`. Why react is not updating the newElement when the button is clicked for the 1st time? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250

Comment: "setState is asynchronous" got it. Thanks