# this.setState not updating state until function called twice

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

I have a function that when I press a button I receive data [an array of objects]. I loop through this array to find one of the objects to store it in the state.

when I click the button the first time, the console log shows that the state was not updated, but when i click it again then it shows that the state was updated:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      listOfItems: [],
      isOpen: false,
      modal: null,
    }
  }
  findKey(key) {
    console.log(key);
    console.log(this.state.listOfItems);
    let foo;
    for (var i in this.state.listOfItems) {
      if (this.state.listOfItems[i].id == key) {
        foo = this.state.listOfItems[i];
        this.setState({ modal: foo });
      }
    }
 // the first time i call the func it returns null- the second time the obj
    console.log(this.state.modal)
  }
```

why is this happening?

thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` function in React is not mutating the `this.state` property, it actually waits for the execution of your function to finish and then triggers a re-render of the component (modify the state and call the render function again).

This means that in order to access your new values, you could use the `render` function, or you could you implement the `componentDidUpdate` function which accepts the old state as a second argument (right after the previous props argument) and can access the new state by using `this.state`.

This allows you to create a much more "Pure" code, which is why React implemented `setState` this way.