# React setState not updating state value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, state, setstate

I have a react app where in the constructor I initialize my displayDate to an empty string. When the app loads, the displayDate value gets set based on the props.

```js
constructor(props){
    this.calendar = null;
    this.state{
        displayedDate: ""
    };
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.calendar = new Calendar({
            format: "MM/DD/YYYY",
            value: this.state.displayedDate
    });
}

componentWillMount(){
    if(this.props.defaultDate){
        this.setState({
            displayedDate: this.convertDateToString(this.props.defaultDate)
        });   
    }
}
// many many more lines of code that follow this

render(){
    return(
        <input type="text"></input>
        <i class="fa fa-calendar" id="calendar"></i>
    );
}
```

In testing the app, I set a breakpoint on `this.setState` in `componentWillMount` and it does indeed enter the `if` block, so the app is receiving the date value from props. But setState doesn't seem to be setting the `displayedDate` to state. And my `convertDateToString` function returns a value, so its not an issue of `displayedDate` getting a void value. In `componentDidMount` I set a breakpoint and dumped the state value and `displayedDate` is still an empty string.

I've seen people experience similar issues like this before, where setState doesn't work as expected. What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Comment: why so complicated? I'd move the code from the lifecycle methods up into the constructor.

Comment: Try displaying `<i class="fa fa-calendar" id="calendar">${this.state}</i>` or `console.log(this.state)` in render function. `setState()` does not apply state changes immediately(as noted by Brian). Once it's applied React will call `render` and will refresh the UI.

Comment: @Thomas I ran into issues with the calendar initialization in the constructor. The calendar has additional fields that are dependent on the rendering of the html elements, so I needed to use some `createRef`s. The consequence was moving the initialization to a lifecycle method so the calendar would initialize after the app loads.