# ReactJS state value not update correctly on input onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my app, i have Groups, and i have a select input, to change between group lists. My issue is when i change the select input, the state changes the name of the list, but is not the one im selecting. For example, at initial i have:

All Groups
Group #1
Group #2

When i choose Group #1, the state in the console says "All Groups". If i choose Group #2, the state in the console says "Group #1"

Select Input

```
<select id="selectedPg" name="selectedPg" onChange={event=> {
    this.valueToState(event.target)
    this.viewProfileGroup();                                        
}}>
```

viewProfileGroup()

```
// View Selected Profile Group
viewProfileGroup = ()=> {
    const {  selectedPg, allProfilesLists } = this.state
 
    this.setState({            
        profilesLists: allProfilesLists.filter(pg => pg.profileGroup === selectedPg)
    })

    console.log(this.state.selectedPg)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [useState set method not reflecting change immediately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/usestate-set-method-not-reflecting-change-immediately)

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately for the correct `setState` syntax to get log your updated value.

Comment: Can you show valueToState's definition? It will help us better understand what is happening.

Comment: Thank you, sure:

```
// Save input values to current state
    valueToState = ({ name, value }) => {
        
        this.setState(() => {
          return { [name]: value };
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the setState is not synchronous, so when you call `this.viewProfileGroup()` and in the method, you are not operating on the latest state.
The solution is simple.
Just pass `event.target` to the `viewProfileGroup` function

```
this.valueToState(event.target)
this.viewProfileGroup(event.target);
```

PS, maybe in this way you will do not need `this.valueToState` at all.