# Why useState not apply new value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I use hook `useState` for set post value.

```js
const [firstPost, setFirstPost] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => { await onFetchPosts(); })();
}, []);

const onFetchPosts = async () => {
    try {
       const { body } = await publicService.fetchPostById(119);

       // get post
       const post = body.posts;
       if (post && post.postsId) {
         console.log(`save...`, body.posts);
         setFirstPost(body.posts);
       }

       console.log(`firstPost...`, firstPost);

     } catch (error) {
         console.log(error);
     } finally {
            setLoading(false);
   }
}
```

[image]

I dont understand, firstPost is not updated.

Comment: Setting the state is a thing that react schedules. It may not be available right in the next line.

Comment: Here is a link explaining it better than I can - https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-react-updates-state/

Comment: thanks, i try read it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0):

This is because `setState` calls are asynchronous. Read it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) and [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate). As the per the doc I linked

> - setState() enqueues changes to the component state and tells React that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the updated state
> - setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall

Therefore, the state is usually not updated yet when you `console.log` it on the next line, but you can access/see the updated state on the next render. If you want to log values, you can put them as inside a `<pre>` tag in your HTML, or do `console.log` at the beginning, like below:

```js
const [firstPost, setFirstPost] = useState();

// Console.log right on at the start of the render cycle
console.log("First post", firstPost);

useEffect(() => {
  (async () => {
    await onFetchPosts();
  })();
}, []);

const onFetchPosts = async () => {
  try {
    const { body } = await publicService.fetchPostById(119);

    // get post
    const post = body.posts;
    if (post && post.postsId) {
      console.log(`save...`, body.posts);
      setFirstPost(body.posts);
    }
    // Do not console.log the state here
    // console.log(`firstPost...`, firstPost);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    setLoading(false);
  }
};

// Can also debug like this
return <pre>{JSON.stringify(firstPost)}</pre>;
```

Comment: i want to use firstPost in orther func, not in template

`
    const listenToScroll = (event) => {
        if (!isLogined) {
            return;
        };
        if (!firstPost || firstPost.read === true) {
            return;
        };
        const relativePost = document.querySelector('.relative-posts');
        if (relativePost) {
            const { offsetTop } = relativePost;
            if (offsetTop - window.scrollY <= 740) {
                onReadPost();
            }
        }
    }
`

Comment: but firstPost in this func is null.

Comment: That seems like an extra problem of how you design the other functions. If you make and edit to the question that includes this other function that is using `firstPost`, I may be able to debug better.

Answer (score 0):

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.
>
> Because this.props and this.state may be updated asynchronously, you should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous

React does not change the state variables immediately when state is changed i.e why you are getting undefined in console.

However the new value of firstPost is assured to be there in the next render.