# React submit form button won't work without clicking more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am working on my first React program, it is the one provided by Sololearn (Contact Manager). I am trying to add a function to search for a contact: SearchName.
However, I need to click many times on the Search button for it to work. Can someone please tell me where I went wrong?
For example, typing *James Smith* in the *enter a name to search* field first gives "is not in list". Then when clicked again, it updates to *is in list*.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function AddPersonForm(props) {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState("");

  function handleChange(e) {
    setPerson(e.target.value);
  }

  function handleSubmit(e) {
    if (person !== "") {
      props.handleSubmit(person);
      setPerson("");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add new contact"
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={person}
      />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
  );
}
function RemovePersonForm(props) {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState("");
  function handleChange(e) {
    setPerson(e.target.value);
  }
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    props.handleSubmit(person);
    setPerson("");
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="enter name to delete"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button type="submit">Delete</button>
    </form>
  );
}

function PeopleList(props) {
  const arr = props.data;
  const listItems = arr.map((val, index) => <li key={index}>{val}</li>);
  return <ul>{listItems}</ul>;
}
function SearchName(props) {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(props.data);
  const [person, setPerson] = useState("");
  const [isInList, setIsInList] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState("");
  function handleChange(e) {
    setPerson(e.target.value);
  }
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    setIsInList(false);
    for (var c of contacts) {
      if (c == person) {
        setIsInList(true);
        break;
      }
    }
    if (isInList) {
      setText("is in list");
    } else {
      setText("is not in list");
    }

    e.preventDefault();
  }
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="enter name to search"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button type="sumbit">Search</button>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </form>
  );
}
function ContactManager(props) {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState(props.data);

  function addPerson(name) {
    setContacts([...contacts, name]);
  }
  function removePerson(name) {
    var newContacts = new Array();
    var i = 0;
    for (var c of contacts) {
      if (c != name) {
        newContacts[i] = c;
        i++;
      }
    }
    setContacts(newContacts);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <AddPersonForm handleSubmit={addPerson} />
      <RemovePersonForm handleSubmit={removePerson} />
      <SearchName data={contacts} />
      <PeopleList data={contacts} />
    </div>
  );
}
const contacts = ["James Smith", "Thomas Anderson", "Bruce Wayne"];

ReactDOM.render(
  <ContactManager data={contacts} />,
  document.getElementById("root"),
);
```

Comment: setState is async here is a link for better understanding [setState is asynchronous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593202/why-calling-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately/42593250)

Answer (score 1):

The root issue is that since `setState` is asynchronous, `isInList` hasn't had the time to change by the time you're checking it in `handleSubmit`.

However, since the printed `text` is strictly a function of whether `isInList` is true, it shouldn't be a separate state atom. If the computation was more complex, I'd recommend using `useMemo` for it.

On a similar note, you shouldn't "fork" the `data` prop to local contacts state.

Finally, you can simplify the finding procedure to a simple `.find` call instead of a loop.

```
function SearchName(props) {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState("");
  const [isInList, setIsInList] = useState(false);
  function handleChange(e) {
    setPerson(e.target.value);
  }
  function handleSubmit(e) {
    setIsInList(props.data.find((c) => c === person));
    e.preventDefault();
  }
  const text = isInList ? "is in list" : "is not in list";
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="enter name to search"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
      <button type="sumbit">Search</button>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </form>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
setIsInList(true);
```

This is an async method, meaning it will be updated after the whole function is executed. To solve this you can use useMemo method as follows (as expalained by @AKX. useEffect shouldnt be used)

```
  const searchResult = useMemo(() => {
    if (isInList) {
      return "is in list";
    } else {
      return "is not in list";
    }
  }, [isInList]);
```

[CodeSandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/fast-grass-zxrft?file=/src/index.js:1732-1923)

Comment: You shouldn't use `useEffect` for state derived from other state (unless asynchronous); just use `useMemo`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because React states only update after an eventHandler is finished - that's something called [batch update](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), In your case, you need to go "another round" to have it updated.

Here is my suggestion from your code:

[Your modified sourcecode](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-rvf9r)

**Keep up the good learning!**